# extract index of duplicate items from one list and merger the items of another list from that index

Tags: python

I have two list

```
ATFIM_Table_Field=['City', 'City', 'Category', 'City', 'Category', 'Category']
ATFIM_Table_Values=['chennai', 'erode', 'printer', 'nagpur', 'pc', 'notebook']
```

I want to find the duplicates in Field and merge the elements of Values at the index of duplicate Field.
expected output- `["'printer','pc','notebook'","'chennai','erode','nagpur'"]`
this is the code i tried:

```
if len(ATFIM_Table_Field) != len(set(ATFIM_Table_Field)):
        newlist=[]
        newelement=[]
        def duplicates(lst, item):
             return [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == item]
        dup=dict((x, duplicates(ATFIM_Table_Field, x)) for x in set(ATFIM_Table_Field) if ATFIM_Table_Field.count(x) > 1)
        duplen=len(dup)
        for i in range(duplen):
            mergevalueindex=list(dup.values())
        for j in range(0,duplen):
            mergevalueindex2=mergevalueindex[j]
            for e in mergevalueindex2:
                newlist.append(ATFIM_Table_Values[e])
                d="','"
                newelement.append("'"+d.join(newlist)+"'")
```

this is the output i am getting:

```
["'printer'",
 "'printer','pc'",
 "'printer','pc','notebook'",
 "'printer','pc','notebook','chennai'",
 "'printer','pc','notebook','chennai','erode'",
 "'printer','pc','notebook','chennai','erode','nagpur'"]
```

Comment: What you want is unclear. Can you add your expected output?

Comment: Yes i did, i want to merge the elements of Values list as one wherever Field value are duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not unclear at all. I understood. Try this:

```
unique_field2indeces = {}
for index in range(len(Field)):
    if Field[index] in list(unique_field2indeces.keys()):
        unique_field2indeces[Field[index]].append(index)
    else:
        unique_field2indeces[Field[index]] = [index]

associated_values = []
for index_list in unique_field2indeces.values():
    value_list = [Values[index] for index in index_list]
    associated_values.append(value_list)
```

Comment: This is your output: `[['chennai', 'erode', 'nagpur'], ['printer', 'pc', 'notebook']]`, this is expected: `["'printer','pc','notebook'","'chennai','erode','nagpur'"]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have shown the exact expected output, then this is the code:

```
Field=['City', 'City', 'Category', 'City', 'Category', 'Category']
Values=['chennai', 'erode', 'printer', 'nagpur', 'pc', 'notebook']
unique_fields = set(Field)
merged_list = []
for field in unique_fields:
    templist = []
    for i,f in enumerate(Field):
        if f == field:
            templist.append(Values[i])
    merged_list.append(str(templist).strip('[\]'))
print(merged_list)
```

Output:

```
["'printer', 'pc', 'notebook'", "'chennai', 'erode', 'nagpur'"]
```